# Kotlin JSR303 Bean Validation doesn’t work from Springboot version 2.3.0.RELEASE onwards

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, bean-validation

Recently working on a project I noticed that **JSR303** Bean Validation doesn’t work from Springboot version **2.3.0.RELEASE** onwards (at least, not in the same way, and I couldn’t figure out what changed even from release doc https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/15/spring-boot-2-3-0-available-now)
for Kotlin.

**Issue:** The bean annotations like **@NotNull, @NotBlank, etc** are ignored and validation doesn’t kick in.

Has someone noticed something similar or have any idea what changed and how to make bean validation work with Springboot **2.3.0.RELEASE** onwards?

here was my setup-

Working setup

```
data class HelloDto(

@field:NotBlank(message = "greeting is required")
val greeting: String,

@field:NotBlank(message = "count is Required")
val count: String
)
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class MyController {

    @PostMapping("/hello")
    fun helloKotlin(@RequestBody @Valid helloDto: HelloDto): String {
        return "hello world "+ helloDto.greeting
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.5.31</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <version>5.1.0</version>
                <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/bank-api.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                            <configOptions>
                                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Request:**

```
{
  "name":"",
  "count":""
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-12-23T16:18:03.177+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotBlank.user.name",
                "NotBlank.name",
                "NotBlank.java.lang.String",
                "NotBlank"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "user.name",
                        "name"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "name",
                    "code": "name"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "must not be blank",
            "objectName": "user",
            "field": "name",
            "rejectedValue": "",
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotBlank"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Validation failed for object='user'. Error count: 1",
    "path": "/users"
}
```

Non Working setup -
As soon as I updated springboot to **2.3.0.RELEASE** the validations were ignored.

**Response:**
[image]

There are 2 reasons why I posted this question -

1. To get some help finding out what changed.
2. To help others not waste so much time due to version issues (I spend a day to find this out)

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this answer in case someone else faces this problem.

The issue was

> Validation Starter no longer included in web starters

So we manually have to add validation dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#spring-boot-23-release-notes